# Xcode is loading in OS X objects instead of iOS objects

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have an iOS window application, which was working fine with Xcode up until today.

When I open the project in the object library it seems to load in all of the OS X development objects, and I can no longer see any of the cocoa touch items like UITextViews, etc.

I didn't manually change any of the settings so I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Make sure it is using the iOS `Base SDK` within the build-settings

Comment: This just happened to me in Xcode 9. How haven't they fixed this yet?

Answer (score 20):

Not sure if its the exact same problem, but I found that opening a `.xib` file switches the Object Library from OS X to iOS objects...

Comment: This fixed the problem for me, opening a storyboard file works just as well.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded **Xcode 4.3.3** last night and had the same problem on my first launch of Xcode after the upgrade.

It certainly **looks like a bug**.  My workaround: in the Build Settings, I changed the "`iOS Deployment Target`" pulldown to a different SDK, then changed it back.  After that, I got the iOS objects **back**.

Comment: Xcode 6.4 still has this bug... and yes switching the deployment target back and forth helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by going File - New - File - Choose "Cocoa Touch" in iOS - choose "Objective-C class - Next - Choose options for your new file: select checkbox "With XIB for user interface"

Answer (score 0):

Changing the deployment target to a different sdk didn't fix it for me.

However, opening up a storyboard brings back the IOS specific objects.

Answer (score 0):

You probably added the Storyboard from the "macOS" tab. Was the icon blue-tinted or yellow-tinted?

yellow-tint -> iOS, watchOS, tvOS

blue-tint   -> macOS