# New "objects library" in Xcode 4.2 with iOS 5

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, ios5, xcode4.2

I am using Xcode 4.2 build 4C199(for MAC OSX 10.6.8). I create a new project and select the AppDelegate.h .m file and close the file. When I reopen the file I see a set of objects in the Objects Library in the Utilities panel that are either new or different. There are many more objects than usual. I'd like to use them, but when I click on either a .xib file or a storyboard file the new objects are replace by the normal old objects .Is there a way to access these new objects? Please refer my screenshots below.

[image] [image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are objects, that are only available on the Mac platform. Please make sure you really created a project targeting the iOS platform. Have a look at the base SDK. It should specify an iOS SDK.

If something went wrong there just create a new project using the right template.

Comment: +1 for the answer buddy....i have recently upgraded to XCode 4.2 directly from 3.2.5. I am using the same project that i'v developed on the older version. Any hints on this??

Comment: i dont understand why i was able to see them if they are MAC secific objects. BTW, i have set my base SDK to iOS 5.....

Comment: I think you are trying to view the Objects Library when you're outside of the StoryBoard editor, if you click on a `.storyboard` file in your project you will see the UI Elements you've learned to love. (I know this is old, but thought I'd help others that see this post)

Answer (score 0):

My project is iOS.  I upgraded Xcode 4.3 to 4.3.3 last night and had the same problem on my first launch of Xcode after the upgrade: the object library contained only OSX objects.

It certainly looks like an Xcode bug. My workaround: in the Build Settings, I changed the "iOS Deployment Target" pulldown to a different SDK, then changed it back. After that, I got the iOS objects back.

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594048/xcode-is-loading-in-os-x-objects-instead-of-ios-objects?answertab=active#tab-top).