# Xcode storyboard showing osX object library. I want IOS object library

Tags: xcode, object, storyboard

I develop mainly IOS apps but, recently, I worked on an OSX app. Both are possible with Xcode (I use 8, with swift).

Unfortunately, when I switched back to my already-existing IOS project (after restarting Xcode), the storyboard selection menu for the object library shows only OSX objects, not IOS (e.g. UIImageView).

I have googled without success and tried restarting Xcode, also without success. Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a lot more searching and came up with:
[Xcode is loading in OS X objects instead of iOS objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594048/xcode-is-loading-in-os-x-objects-instead-of-ios-objects)

There there are other solutions proposed but the one that worked for me was to close the assistant editor and then, in the file list ( leftmost window in Xcode 8), I double clicked on the storyboard file. Problem solved. I am surprised that this bug still exists in this latest version...it is very troublesome.